# Code Completion for Delphi Namespaces

Tags: delphi, namespaces

Is there a way to have units I create show up in code completion when I am entering dotnet style unit names?  For example, if I type "System.", I get a popup containing the names of units that are part of the namespace, such as Class, SysUtil, etc.  If I created my own library with a namespace of MyLib (I know.  Very original), installed it as a package, I would want a popup listing all of the units in the namespace when I type "MyLib."

FYI, I am using Delphi 10 Seattle and have already created an entry in "Unit Scope Names."  The entry is MyLib;MyLib.Frameworks;MyLib.Forms;MyLib.General. Each of these have actual units as part of there namespaces, none of which populates the Code Insight list.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is automatically enabled with default Delphi installations. Unless you've disabled it, it should already do this. Bear in mind though that the Delphi IDE is known for flukes which prevent such features from working as expected.

Comment: @JerryDodge It only works for the first dot, any after that don't - you can confirm that by typing System.Generics. It should list Collections and Defaults but it does not.

Comment: It works for the rlt and vcl, but not for libraries I create.  Is there a way for Delphi to provide this same functionality for my libraries?

Comment: Unit name completion has been broken since namespace introduction. My suggestion is switch to CnPack.